# Is there a subtle difference between !myVar and myVar === undefined?

Tags: javascript

Is there any subtle difference between

```
if(myVar === undefined) {
  // whatev
}
```

and

```
if(!myVar) {
  // whatev
}
```

and if so which one is the best practice ?

Comment: myVar = false will enter the if in second case but not in first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: If you don't know the difference between falsy values and undefined in JS, you'd better stick to second approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if(myVar === undefined) {   // whatev }

This if statement will execute only if myVar is `undefined`.

Whereas the other statement:

```
if(!myVar) {
  // whatev
}
```

Will execute if myVar is `undefined` or `null` or `false` or `0` or `""` or any other falsy value.

So based on your requirement. If you want to execute for only `undefined` values, select first option else go for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference.

```
if(myVar === undefined) {
  // whatev
}
```

only checks if it is really `undefined`

```
if(!myVar) {
  // whatev
}
```

checks for a `falsy` value, which could be `0`, `false`, `''`, ,`undefined`, `null`  or any other falsy value

An empty Array also can be a falsy value if you check

```
let arr = [];

if(!arr.length){} // falsy since the lenght is 0 which is falsy
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are the differences

let me explain you with example.

```js
var myVar ; //just declared, so by default it has value undefined, undefined is a 
//primitive value automatically assigned to variables that have just been declared,

console.log(myVar === undefined) // this should print true
console.log(!myVar) // this should also print true as it converts it into truthy or falsy value
```

now suppose

```js
var myVar = "" ; //declared and assigned empty string

console.log(myVar === undefined) // this should print false, as "" is not undefined
console.log(!myVar) // this should  print true as "" is converted into falsy value and negation convert it into truthy
```

read about  [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values and `[undefined][2]` in Java Script